# Laravel or PHP unique with multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to get the unique rows from a MySQL DB from PHP and Laravel.

In my DB I have:

```
Email    Errors   Status  
a@a.a    error1   pending
a@a.a    error2   pending
b@b.b    error1   pending
b@b.b    error1   pending
```

In my head the solution would be:

```
$transactions->unique('email', 'errors', 'status' )
```

But that's returning this:

```
Email    Errors   Status  
a@a.a    error1   pending
b@b.b    error1   pending
```

And if I try:

```
$transactions->unique(['email', 'errors', 'status'] )
```

It's even worse:

```
Email    Errors   Status  
a@a.a    error1   pending
```

My perfect solution would be this, so I can see the different errors from each user:

```
Email    Errors   Status  
a@a.a    error1   pending
a@a.a    error2   pending
b@b.b    error1   pending
```

That means unique based on several columns.

I was searching everywhere without success, I hope somebody can help :)

Comment: Is `$transactions` a collection?

Comment: It seems like it would be better to do it in the database using group by instead of in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can...

1) either provide your own function as `unique` predicate:

```
$transactions->unique(function ($item) {
    return $item['email'].'/'.$item['errors'].'/'.$item['status'];
});
```

... assuming that `/` symbol is never used in either field.

2) or make such a grouping on query level, using `groupBy` method:

```
$DB::table('transactions')->select('email', 'errors', 'status')
->groupBy('email')
->groupBy('errors')
->groupBy('status')
->get();
```

I'd rather go with the latter.

Comment: Thank you very much, the last one has worked perfect. Well, I have more selects than columns to groupBy, so I'm figuring out how to do it. I think with some short of concat or something like that.