# Laravel, select and groupBy - DB::raw - issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've been trying to solve this, my first problem [was this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573469/laravel-or-php-unique-with-multiple-conditions) and its kind of working as expected.

The problem is that I can't select more columns than the ones in groupBy, so I've found a solution: `DB::raw('created_at as created_at')`

But it's returning me this:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 created_at' isn't in GROUP BY
```

Ad if I add "create_at" `groupBy(DB::raw('create_at'))` and "concept" to groupBy, then they are grouped that is what I want to try to avoid.

My code is:

```
@forelse($transaction->where('status', '!=', 'ok')
                      ->select('user_id', 'option_id', 'status', 'concept', DB::raw('created_at as created_at'), DB::raw('concept as concept'))
                      ->groupBy('user_id')
                      ->groupBy('option_id')
                      ->groupBy('status')
                      ->get() as $transaction)

{{$transaction->concept}}
{{$transaction->created_at}}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, thanks to @noufalcep and @Rob Fonseca Rob, I came with this solution, I think this happens in Laravel after versión 5.4 where strict is set to true.

So instead of disabling it completely I did this:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            //'strict' => true, #####I COMMENTED THIS####
            'modes' => [
                        //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', #####AND THIS####
                        'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                        'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                        'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                        'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                        'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
                        'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
            ],
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

By the way, MAX MIN didn't work for me, it was still requesting to add it into groupBy and asking for an array

I hope this will help the next one.

Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Every column in a SELECT statement must also be in the GROUP BY clause.

There is a exception by setting the *only_full_group_by* mode to false in MySQL 5.7.5 or higher, but the assumption is the extra columns have the same value for all rows
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

You can also accomplish this by using tricks to get a MAX() or MIN() for the non-grouped columns but you can not get the actual values of those columns for each row unless they are added to the GROUP BY statement

Answer (score 2):

Mysql strict mode is enabled by default. Disable strict mode, it will solve your issue.

In config/database.php under `'mysql'`

```
'strict' => true,
```

to false.

```
'strict' => false,
```

Comment: Commenting that line is equal to setting it to false. If its unsecure, laravel does not provide an option to disable it.